# WCF Rest Stream + Dictionary

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, c#-4.0, stream

I need to consume in the WCF REST Service dictionary/ list and stream.

What is the proper way to do it? I have some interface like this:

```
public interface ITestService
{

    [OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "/Upload?dic={dic}")]
    IAsyncResult BeginUpload(Dictionary<string, guid> dic, Stream stream, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);

...
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? For example post a sample method signature.